# Dccp protocol simulation in ns2 2.34

Tags: patch, dccp

How to add dccp patches to ns2 2.34? Please give me detailed steps.

The file is the file is `ns234-dccp-1.patch`.

The error comes when I try to simulate dccp is

```
Kar@ubuntu:~$ ns audiodccp.tcl 
invalid command name "Agent/DCCP/TCPlike" 
    while executing 
"Agent/DCCP/TCPlike create _o726 " 
    invoked from within 
"catch "$className create $o $args" msg" 
    invoked from within 
"if [catch "$className create $o $args" msg] { 
if [string match "__FAILED_SHADOW_OBJECT_" $msg] { 
delete $o 
return "" 
} 
global errorInfo 
error "class $..." 
    (procedure "new" line 3) 
    invoked from within 
"new Agent/DCCP/TCPlike" 
    invoked from within 
"set dccp1 [new Agent/DCCP/TCPlike]" 
    (file "audiodccp.tcl" line 50)
```

**UBUNTU-10.04
NS2 allinone 2.34**

Answer (score 0):

---

audiodccp.tcl : Unknown file.

> invalid command name "Agent/DCCP/TCPlike"

→ → You have a failed build. Or you are using the wrong executable 'ns'. The suggestion is to do :

```
cd ns-allinone-2.34/-ns-2.34/
cp ns ns-dccp
sudo cp ns-dccp /usr/local/bin/
```

... and then do simulations with `$ ns-dccp [file.tcl]`

You can also use ns-2.35, which has DCCP included by default.

Note : You can have as many times ns-allinone-2.xx as you want, installed at the same time. But : Do never add any PATH text to .bashrc. Not required.

---

---